# logout on browser closed spring mvc

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security, browser

When I closed the browser the logged in person will automatically need to logout. Is there any solution for it. Please help me. I'm working with spring MVC. As we close the window of gmail we are automatically logout. Is there any special method we need to implement. Any one has an idea please share.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the browser will force the user to login again when coming back to the webapp. But that doesn't mean its session is automatically closed at server-side. It means that the session cookie will be forgotten by the browser.

There is no way around it. You can't control what happens at client-side. That's why the sessions have a timeout.